# Problema de segmentación en C++

Tags: c++

Algo así es el código, es mucho mas complejo y extenso, y todo va ligado uno con el otro, pero dejo un resumen de como trabaja, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

```
    struct propietario{

    string nombre;
    string apellido1;
    string apellido2;
    int cedula;
    list <struct autos>susautos;                    //relacion de propietario con auto
    };

    struct autos{

    int placa;
    int year;
    int cantPasajeros;
    string tipo;
    list <struct sucursalAuto>Sucursal;   //relacion de auto con sucursal

    };
    struct sucursalAuto{
    string name;
    int codigo;
    };

    list<propietario> listaPropietario;
```

De la siguiente forma, ingreso el usuario.

```
    void RegistrarUsuario (){

    cout << "Nombre del propietario" << endl;
    string nombre;
    cin >> nombre; 
    cout << "Pimer Apellido" << endl;
    string Apellido1;
    cin >> Apellido1;
    cout << "Segundo Apellido" << endl;
    string Apellido2;
    cin >> Apellido2;

    cout << "Cedula" << endl;
    int cedula;
    cin>> cedula;
    if(buscarPropietario(cedula)){
    propietario Prop = {nombre,Apellido1,Apellido2,cedula};

    listaPropietario.push_back(Prop); //así envio el propietario a la lista

    }
```

De esta forma agrego los datos al struct auto para luego mandarlos a la sublista de `propietario(susAutos)`

```
 void agregar auto(){
    cout<<"Año modelo del vheiculo" <<endl;
    int modelo;
    cin>>modelo;
    cout<<"Cantidad de pasajeros del vheiculo"<<endl;
    int cant;
    cin>>cant;
    cout<< "Tipo de Vehiculo:" << endl << "1.Liviano" << endl << "2.Gubernamental"<< endl <<"3.Carga Liviana"<<endl;
    int tipo;
    cin>> tipo;
    string tipoAuto;
    if (tipo==1){  
    tipoAuto="Liviano";

    autos autox = {placAuto,modelo, cant,tipoAuto};
    posProp->susautos.push_back(autox);  //De esta manera ligo el vehiculo al dueño

    }
```

En esta parte es donde se me presenta el error, la idea es mandar a la sublista de sucursal declarada en el struct autos, pero como que la variable sucursal no es leida por el programa

```
void ingresoSucursal(){
cout<<"NOMBRES DE LA SUCURSAL";
string name;
int codigo;
sucursalAuto suc = {name,codigo}; //Aquí es donde se presenta el error, ya que incluso he dejado sin rellanar el corchete con las dos varias(ejemplo: sucursalAuto suc = {name};) y no marca error.

posAuto->Sucursal.push_back(suc);   

}
```

Obviamente le indico a los iteradores donde deben apuntar ejemplo;

```
 posPro= listaPropietario.begin();
 posAuto= posProp->susAutos;
```

Comment: La idea es relacionar  con listas así=  Propietario[susautos(Sucursal)]

Comment: Se agradecería que presentases un ejemplo mínimo y completo que pudiésemos probar... con el código que pones es complicado ya que faltan variables y contexto. La línea que señalas, tal cual está, no debería dar problemas... otra cosa es que los iteradores no apunten a donde crees o cosas así... pero poco más te puedo decir

Comment: @user127400 no puedes acceder a elementos de listas usando corchetes.